# Stratonovich integral $\int_0^T W_t \circ dW_t$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, riemann-sum

I am trying to teach myself some stochastic calculus and am struggling to derive a Stratonovich integral. I am trying to understand how, considering the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^T W_t \circ dW_t
\end{equation}

we get the Riemann sum
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow& \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} W(\frac{t_{j+1} - t_j}{2}) ( W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_{j}))\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vdots\\
&=\frac{1}{2} (W^2(T) -W^2(0)) + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}( W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_{j})).
\end{align}

Can anyone provide the identity used to get the last step above (simplifying the Riemann sum) or show how to get to the final step from the initial definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for Stratanovich integral is wrong - the correct sum should be

$$\sum\frac{W(t_{j+1})+W(t_j)}{2}(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_j))=\frac12\sum W^2(t_{j+1})-W^2(t_j)=\frac12 W^2(T)-\frac12 W^2(0).$$

Comment: Thank you @user843000

Comment: @Sonji Actually the Riemman sum given by the OP is not incorrect, they are equivalent, see Th.8.3.7 on "Introduction to Stochastic Integration" by H.H.Kuo